# How can I improve this boolean function?

Tags: python, optimization

I often find myself returning a boolean from a method, that's used in multiple locations, in order to contain all the logic around that method in a single place. All the (internal) calling method needs to know is whether the operation was successful, or not.

I'm using Python but the question isn't necessarily specific to that language. There are only two options I can think of
Raise an exception, though the circumstances are not exceptional, and remember to catch that exception in every place the function is called
Return a boolean as I'm doing.

This is a really simple example that demonstrates what I'm talking about.

```
import os

class DoSomething(object):

    def remove_file(self, filename):

        try:
            os.remove(filename)
        except OSError:
            return False

        return True

    def process_file(self, filename):

        do_something()

        if remove_file(filename):
            do_something_else()
```

Although it works, its a bad design.
How can I improve this?

Comment: Why is it bad design?  If you gave this to another coder and asked him/her to read the code, would they know what's going on?

Comment: looks fine to me. Just that you can get rid of try-except, and check if file exists and delete. It would look cleaner

Comment: I can use os.path.exists(filename) prior to attempting deletion but there's no guarantees the file won't have been locked in the meantime and I still have to determine whether the deletion has been successful or not.

Comment: @KulvinderBisla: Agreed that you don't want to use `os.path.exists` here, but… what's the problem you're trying to solve? Is it that you want to handle no-such-file differently from other reasons the deletion might fail?

Comment: The exception on `os.remove(filename)` is raised only when `filename` is a directory.  Otherwise, it returns nothing.  So, what you're doing in `remove_file` is returning `True` if `filename` isn't a directory.  It doesn't seem to care whether a file was actually removed or not?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on code review?

Comment: This is bad design. You should let the exception propegate. All you are doing here is giving the caller less information, and making it easier to ignore the problem. You gain nothing by doing this.

Comment: Nobody's said this yet, but what is the purpose of having a class here?  your class has 2 methods, neither of which use `self` at all.  If you're not going to use `self` in any of your methods, you should really ask yourself if you should have a class in the first place.

Comment: There are _some_ cases where this is a good idea. For example, if you're passing a callback into someone else's low-level bindings around a C library, it may well demand a boolean result and not handle exceptions nicely. But Lattyware is right that, when there are no such considerations, the right way to deal with exceptions is to propagate them to the point where you can deal with them.

Comment: Is this tagged "optimization" for a reason? If you think exceptions are too slow and you're trying to speed things up… see [How fast are exceptions?](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions) in the FAQ, but the short version is that anything you to avoid propagating exceptions will slow things down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building upon @Joran Beasley's answer, I'd put the something else in an else block:

```
class DoSomething(object):

    def process_file(self, filename):

        do_something()

        try:
            os.remove(filename)
        except OSError:
            return False
        else:
            do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to solve here, but this comment seems illuminating:

> I can use `os.path.exists(filename)` prior to attempting deletion but there's no guarantees the file won't have been locked in the meantime and I still have to determine whether the deletion has been successful or not.

There's also no guarantees that the file won't have been deleted, or replaced with a different file, etc. in the mean time. So, you're right that you shouldn't use `os.path.exists`.

But what's the problem here? Just try to delete it. If the file didn't exist, you get an exception. If the file is locked or otherwise fails to delete, you get an exception. Either way, the delete failed.

If the issue is distinguishing one failure reason from the others so you can handle it specially, that's easy:

```
try:
    os.remove(filename)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Oops, {} doesn't exist".format(filename))
except OSError as e:
    print('Got {} trying to delete {}'.format(e, filename))
else:
    do_something_else()
```

---

If you're using an earlier version of Python than 3.3, you don't have [`FileNotFoundError`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError), so… it's a bit less beautiful, but the same idea:

```
try:
    os.remove(filename)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOENT
        print("Oops, {} doesn't exist".format(filename))
    else:
        print('Got {} trying to delete {}'.format(e, filename))
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: +1 Think you put it better than me - possibly a `Got {!r}...` instead though

Comment: I'm not sure. `str` generally has more useful information than the `repr`, as well as being intended for human-readability. (Although in this case, part of that "more information" is usually going to be the filename, so maybe it was silly of me adding that explicitly…) On the other hand, it doesn't included the exception type, which may be handy on its own (especially in 3.3)…

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can think of that the OP was bad design is that: typically in python there are two schools of thought **Look before you leap** and **Easier to ask permission than forgiveness** , but in your code you are doing both . usually you just pick one or the other

```
class DoSomething(object):

    def process_file(self, filename):

        do_something()

        try:
            os.remove(filename)
        except OSError:
            return False
        else:
            do_something_else()
```

is much cleaner imho

Answer (score 2):

In this case it's fine to let (or raise) an exception. The whole idea is that flow-control can be handled at a level that understands the "bigger picture" and might be able to do something about it. The inner parts carry merrily on their way without having to check boolean flags.

For instance, if removing the file fails - is it catastrophic - presumably your inner function doesn't know, so it shouldn't mask the stack trace. Higher up, it might be able to retry or just decide that actually it's not so bad, let's carry on regardless. Forcing exceptions into returns means that information is lost and requires the user to remember to actually check return results - also, some functions may have genuine boolean return results so the only way to identify those will be via handling exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess if you really wanted to go for removing the "boolean", you could use a lambda like

```
def remove_file(self, filename, success):
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
    except OSError:
        //error stuff
    else:
        success()

def process_file(self, filename):
    do_something()
    remove_filename(filename, lambda: do_something_else())
```

You can pass how many parameters you want to the function then wrap it in the lambda, so the success function will only execute when removing the fill was successful.  Though, I don't see anything wrong with your initial code.

Comment: The `lambda` adds nothing here. Regular functions are first-class values in Python, in exactly the same way lambdas are. Just pass `do_something_else` as the callback.

Comment: Meanwhile, this looks like someone trying to write JavaScript or Ruby code in Python, instead of writing Python code. And, more seriously, it looks like you're expecting that `remove_filename` is going to be asynchronous, because that's the only time anyone writes code like this in Python—and, for that matter, the most common reason they do so in JS. So, this will mislead your readers. (And even if you _do_ need to be asynchronous, you _still_ don't need a callback. Look up Greg Ewing's tutorials, and [PEP 3156](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/), for a more pythonic solution.)

Comment: Ah, didn't know that @abarnert, thank you.  Though I do use Javascript at work, the languages I use personally are functional where lambda has to be explicitly stated.

Comment: In Haskell, ML, etc., a reference (name, symbol, etc.) of a named functions can also be used wherever a lambda can (possibly subject to quoting in Lisp-like languages), so the lambda is just as unnecessary in those languages as in Python.

Comment: And the JS/Ruby comment wasn't about the unnecessary lambda, it was about using a "success callback" instead of a return even when there's no good reason to do so.